# OpenGL doesn't draw when I have an "out" in vertex shader

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, glsl

I have a a vertex shader and a fragment shader.  I am sending in a color variable in the buffer to the vertex shader, and then trying to pass it to the fragment shader.  When I have an `out vec4 out_color` in my code, nothign is drawn.  My code is

```
"in vec4 in_position;\n"
"in vec4 in_color;\n"
"out vec4 out_color;"
"void\nmain()\n"
"{\n"
"  gl_Position = in_position;\n"
"out_color = in_color;"
"}\n\n";
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Can't you load that from a file, rather than sticking it in a string like that? In any case, does the shader compile?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"out_color = in_color;"`?

Comment: sorry. out_color is what is in my code

Comment: And Nicol, Yes I can, does it make a difference though?

Comment: @James No, but it would certainly improve the question format. But nevermind, his question if the shader compiles and the program links correctly is more important.

Comment: @James Ah, I see. It makes a difference, will make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the newline after the declaration of `out_color` in your shader string. So it is on the same line as `void main()` (in which you also have a newline, but that might not be a problem).

For the sake of clarity, I would suggest you to always use one substring for a single line and always include a newline at the end of each substring, if you really want to use in-code shader code, anyway.

And you should also always check if your shaders compiled correctly and the program linked correctly and query the info log in case they didn't. This would have told you the error quite obviously (or at least would have given you a hint).

Comment: @James So then look at my last paragraph and tell us what the info log says.

Comment: There are no warnings in info log

Comment: @James You query [glGetShaderiv](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShader.xml) and [glGetProgramiv](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetProgram.xml) with `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` and `GL_LINK_STATUS` respectively.

Comment: @James And you're sure your fragment shader has an `in vec4 out_color;`? If not this might result in a link error.

Comment: Yes I am sure, and just to be clear: what would the code look like to the glGetSHaderiv.

Comment: @James `int status; glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);` same for link status (but with program instead of shader) and info log length (again for both). Just look at the respective links in my comment.

Comment: sorry but the last thing I don't understand is how to get the info log of status.  If i use cout it just prints "1"

Comment: @James You query the info log length (using `glGet...iv`) and then the log itself using [`glGet...InfoLog`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml). For both shaders and for the program, of course. How can you say that "there are no warnings in info log" when you don't know how to retrieve it?

Comment: @James: The [OpenGL Wiki page on GLSL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language#Error_Checking) has full example code for error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong version of the shading language
you must include the code at the top of both shaders

```
#version 140;
```